# Regex: How to determine if a string contains the entire set of a given substring?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have an array of substrings `['abcd', 'xyz', '091823', '9-+#$_#$*']. How can I use regex to make sure that a given string contains ALL of these?

Comment: All of these characters ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: A little explanation to that would be helpful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I understood your regex but how is it relevant to question ? Question itself is unclear as to OP is talking about those characters or pattern in one string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think this answers the question of how to test a given string for containing all of the strings in the array. I think my answer does that for THIS array of strings. For any array of substrings t would be a more complex problem that requires escaping metacharacters but I'm not sure if Alan is asking that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lookarounds:

```
/(?=.*abcd)(?=.*xyz)(?=.*091823)(?=.*9-\+#\$_#\$\*)/
```

For the general case of any array of strings to test:

```
function containsAll(str, arrayOfStr) {
  return new RegExp(arrayOfStr.map(function (s) {
    return '(?=.*' + s.replace(/([-\\[\]{}.^$+*()|?])/g, '\\$1') + ')';
  }).join('')).test(str);
}

containsAll(str, ['abcd', 'xyz', '091823', '9-+#$_#$*']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take a dynamic array of search terms and check whether another string contains all of the search terms. I don't think you will find a regex-only solution; you should loop through the terms and check each one individually. Also, if the terms are dynamic you probably don't want to use regex unless you know they don't need sanitization (for example, '9-+#$_#$*' contains special regex characters).

Here is a sample solution:

```js
var terms = ['abcd', 'xyz', '091823', '9-+#$_#$*'];
var tests = {
  success: 'abcd 091823 xyz 9-+#$_#$*',
  failure: 'abcd 091823 xyz'
}

var testKeys = Object.keys(tests);
for(var test of testKeys){
  var pass = true;
  for(var term of terms){
    if(tests[test].indexOf(term) == -1){
      pass = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += `${test}: ${pass}<br>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking ES6, you are able to use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method without using Regular Expressions:

```js
// When `str` doesn't contain all substrings
var str = 'there is no desired substring here';

result = ['abcd', 'xyz', '091823', '9-+#$_#$*'].every(function(e) {
   return str.includes(e);
});

console.log(result);
```